# Vite + React: sudo npm run build failed

Tags: reactjs, vite

I having issues deploying my production server using Vite + React:

```
/var/www/html/dev-sp-doc/node_modules/vite/bin/vite.js:2
import { performance } from 'node:perf_hooks'
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sp-doc@0.0.0 build: `tsc && vite build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sp-doc@0.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

node v19.5.0
vite ^3.2.5

Comment: What is the value of `compilerOptions.target` in your `tsconfig.json` file?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue?